# Powershell Global scope with concurrent script execution

Tags: powershell, scope

I am writing a script to power off and power on VM's from a list of servers the user provides.

In a function I verify that the server exists in our environment and need to track the good servers I actually power off in an array.  In order to solve a scope issue for this array variable I was going to make it global, but am wondering if a global variable would be affected if multiple users ran this script from the same server at the same time, since I know it would be in scope for the shell.

I have tried to run script level scope but it does not seem to work for me properly.  Does anyone know if global would cause an issue in this case?

ex:

```
$powerOn = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($server in $servers){
      powerOff($server)
}

Function powerOff($name){
      #Code to check if server exists
      #if exists
      $Global:powerOn.add($name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the scope every time you refer to a non-local variable:

```
$Global:powerOn = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
foreach ($server in $servers){
      powerOff($server)
}

Function powerOff($name){
      #Code to check if server exists
      #if exists
      $Global:powerOn.add($name)
}
```

This should also allow you to use the `script` scope if you'd rather.